# How can I download latest build with Ansible win_get_url module?

Tags: ansible, repository

I try to download the **latest installation file** from our JFrog repository with the following task:

```yaml
- name: Download Server.msi file from JFrog repository
  ansible.windows.win_get_url:
    url: "{{ jfrog_url }}/Product/20.100.999.4112/x64/Server.msi"
    dest: C:\Server.msi
    url_username: "{{ jfrog_username }}"
    url_password: "{{ jfrog_password }}"
    validate_certs: no
```

Currently, the URL points to a specific version (i.e `/20.100.999.4112/`) 
As you can see the folder name hold the version number of the build 
How can I edit this task in a way that it will download latest file each time?

Comment: Find a resource that lists the releases.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider After a search I made - we have no such a thing. What are my options in this situation? and can I concatenate a (latest) build.timestamp or (latest) build.number variable to the url?

Comment: You need some way to get the highest available version. If you don't have one you will have to change it manually. A directory listing would be sufficient.

Comment: It sounds like this is an internal server under your control. If you configure it to allow directory listing under `{{ jfrog_url }}/Product/` that would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

> ***How can I edit this task in a way that it will download latest file each time?***

A minimal example playbook (*... which is similar working in a production environment*) will catch the latest version first

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost # controlnode.example.com
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  
  vars:
  
    jfrog_url: artifactory.example.com
  
  tasks:

  - name: Get latest version from internal repository
    uri:
      url: "https://{{ jfrog_url }}/api/storage/Product/?lastModified"
      method: GET
      url_username: "{{ jfrog_username }}"
      url_password: "{{ jfrog_password }}"
      validate_certs: true
      return_content: true
      status_code: 200
      body_format: json
    register: response
    check_mode: false

  - set_fact:
      filename: '{{ response.json.uri.split("/")[8] }}'
      version: '{{ response.json.uri.split("-")[2] }}'
```

Please take note that it will be necessary to adjust the parse and split task of the `response.json.uri` in order the get the correct `filename` and `version` from the custom data structure. After it can become downloaded

```yaml
  - name: Download file from internal repository
    delegate_to: windows.example.com
    win_get_url:
      url: "https://{{ jfrog_url }}/Product/{{ filename }}"
      url_username: "{{ jfrog_username }}"
      url_password: "{{ jfrog_password }}"
      dest: "C:\Server-{{ version }}.msi"
```

**Documentation**

- [Get Last Modified Item](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/get-last-modified-item)